# When to use `static_assert` instead of SFINAE?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, static-assert

I have been using (and seen used) `static_assert` to flag undesired values of template parameter values. However, for all cases I came across it seems better and more elegant to disable those undesired values via SFINAE.

For example:

```cpp
template<typename T,
         class = std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type>
struct Foo { ... };
```

instead of:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    static_assert(std::is_floating_point<T>::value,
                  "Foo<T>: T must be floating point :-(");
    ...
};
```

So my question: when should I use `static_assert` instead of SFINAE and why?

**EDIT:**

I think what I've learned so far is the following:

**1.** SFINAE is a versatile and powerful but potentially very complicated tool that can be used for many tasks, including function overload resolution (which some seem to regard as its only purpose).

**2.** SFINAE can be used in a relatively simple way wherever `static_assert` can, except that it appears in the *declaration* (of a class or function) rather than its *definition* (or is is possible to insert a `static_assert` into, say, a class forward declaration?). That makes more verbatim and hence clearer code. However, because SFINAE is complicated, it tends to be harder to get right than a simple `static_assert`.

**3.** On the other hand `static_assert` has the benefit of a clearer compiler error message, which some seem to regard as the main purpose of both.

Comment: Can you explain why you think it's better with SFINAE?

Comment: Maybe our answers are oriented by the vocabulary. In you question I think you should replace SFINAE by `std::enable_if`. It sounds strange to want to generate an error with a mechanism that emphasis on the fact that it is not an error. SFINAE = Substitution Failure Is Not An Error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think `static_assert` is the right choice if you want to enforce that `T` is a floating point type. This method states your intent more clearly than the SFINAE solution.

Comment: I disagree. consider the forward declaration `template<typename> class some_class;`. How can I know that that class only accepts integral type template parameters if the `static_assert` comes only in the class definition?

Comment: @Walter SFINAE is not applicable in this instance, so how does it matter? In any case with a bit of gymnastics you can write something like `template<typename T, Requires<std::is_integral<T>>...> class some_class;` (where `Requires` is a trick like those used in Boost.Concepts), although I cannot vouch for the legitimacy (and portability) of such a thing.

Answer (score 19):

You use SFINAE, if you want another overload to be used, and `static_assert` if none of them would fit such parameter.

Answer (score 14):

`static_assert` makes the compilation fail. SFINAE allows you to remove one possible overload.

Comment: In the case shown, both make compilation to fail if you write `Foo<int>`.

Comment: SFINAE disables a certain template parameter. If the compiler cannot find another match, compilition will fail.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I just read your blog/page on *Remastered enable_if* and was missing the definition of the template `all<>` used to combine several condition types. Where can I find it?

Comment: @Walter it's on a previous post: http://rmartinho.github.com/2012/05/29/type-traits-galore.html#conditions_and_logical_metaops

Answer (score 6):

For one, using SFINAE may lead to another overload being picked that was originally a worse match and wouldn't be considered.

And in the situation that there are other overloads, but non of them is viable, you get some nice things like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

void f(int){}
void f(bool){}
void f(char){}
void f(float){}
void f(long){}
void f(double){}
void f(short){}
void f(unsigned){}
void f(void*){}
void f(void (*)()){}

template<class C, class T = int>
using EnableIf = typename std::enable_if<C::value, T>::type;

template<class T>
struct sfinae_false : std::false_type{};

template<class T> 
void f(T&&, EnableIf<sfinae_false<T>> = 0){}

int main(){ struct X{}; f(X()); }
```

Output:

```
source.cpp: In function 'int main()':
source.cpp:23:30: error: no matching function for call to 'f(main()::X)'
source.cpp:23:30: note: candidates are:
source.cpp:3:6: note: void f(int)
source.cpp:3:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'main()::X' to 'int'
source.cpp:4:6: note: void f(bool)
source.cpp:4:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'main()::X' to 'bool'
source.cpp:5:6: note: void f(char)
source.cpp:5:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'main()::X' to 'char'
source.cpp:6:6: note: void f(float)
source.cpp:6:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'main()::X' to 'float'
source.cpp:7:6: note: void f(long int)
source.cpp:7:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'main()::X' to 'long int'
source.cpp:8:6: note: void f(double)
source.cpp:8:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'main()::X' to 'double'
source.cpp:9:6: note: void f(short int)
source.cpp:9:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'main()::X' to 'short int'
source.cpp:10:6: note: void f(unsigned int)
source.cpp:10:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'main()::X' to 'unsigned int'
source.cpp:11:6: note: void f(void*)
source.cpp:11:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'main()::X' to 'void*'
source.cpp:12:6: note: void f(void (*)())
source.cpp:12:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'main()::X' to 'void (*)()'
source.cpp:21:6: note: template<class T> void f(T&&, EnableIf<sfinae_false<T> >)
source.cpp:21:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

Comment: A nasty property of SFINAE is that you need to make sure that multiple overloads have non-overlapping conditions, otherwise you still get an error. I greatly prefer tag dispatching for selective overloading.

Comment: Given that the example in the question is a class template rather than a function template, does this answer amount to "you are correct for classes, but haven't considered functions"? Or are there advantages to static asserts for classes too?

Comment: @SteveJessop: Well, SFINAE doesn't really apply to class templates, since it *is* a hard error there ("no member named 'type'  in 'std::enable_if<false>' ...).

Comment: **1** I disagree that SFINAE doesn't apply to classes. **2** I agree that for functions SFINAE may result in undesired surprises. **3** I think that SFINAE is much easier to mess up and get wrong (as in this answer) than `static_assert`

Comment: using SFINAE on the type of a function argument is always dangerous. Better to use it on the return type.

Comment: @Walter: It's not "dangerous", it's just something I used here because I felt like it. Normally, I employ [new-style SFINAE](http://rmartinho.github.com/2012/06/01/almost-static-if.html) or [expression SFINAE](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2634.html).

Comment: @Walter SFINAE only applies to so-called template argument deduction, which is only available to function templates, not class templates. This doesn't mean that your example cannot be used in tandem with SFINAE (I suspect that `template<typename T> void foo(T, Foo<T> = {});` is such a situation), but it is far from idiomatic: code involved in SFINAE is usually left to function templates, and not pushed to class templates. Use of `std::enable_if` in code is neither necessary nor sufficient for SFINAE.

Comment: @Luc "which is only available to function templates". That's not actually true. SFINAE is active during argument deduction for class template partial specializations too.

Comment: @LucDanton **NO** You can disable a class template with SFINAE, for example by having an additional template parameter defaulting to `std::enable_if<condition_on_first_parameter>::type`. Such a class can be invoked for a first parameter not matching the condition only by explicitily providing a second parameter, i.e. by deliberate deceit. Such cases can then still be caught with a `static_assert`.

Comment: @Walter My point still stands. Such ‘disabling’ will only occur during overload resolution for a function template or, as Johannes rightfully pointed out, class template specialization selection. While this technique is available, I’ve never seen a use for it—it should be clearer to put the constraints on the function templates/class template specialization directly. Concepts-lite, which adapts present practice into actual language features, has no equivalent either (e.g. no `requires` clause allowed on a primary template declaration).