# std::hash specialization using sfinae?

Tags: c++, c++14, template-specialization, sfinae

As an exercise I was trying to see if I could use SFINAE to create a `std::hash` specialization for `std::pair` and `std::tuple` when all of its template parameters are of an unsigned type. I have a little experience with them, but from what I understand the hash function needs to have already been templated with a `typename Enabled = void` for me to add a specialization. I'm not really sure where to go from here. Here's an attempt which doesn't work.

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <utility>

namespace std {
template <typename T, typename Enabled = void>
struct hash<std::pair<T, T>, std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>>
{
    size_t operator()(const std::pair<T, T>& x) const
    {
        return x;
    }
};
}; // namespace std


int
main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    std::unordered_set<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>> test{};
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
hash_sfinae.cpp:7:42: error: default template argument in a class template partial specialization
template <typename T, typename Enabled = void>
                              ^
hash_sfinae.cpp:8:8: error: too many template arguments for class template 'hash'
struct hash<std::pair<T, T>, std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>>
```

It's about what I expected because I'm trying to extend the template parameters to hash... But I'm not sure the technique to handle these cases then. Can someone help me understand?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not supposed to specialize `std::hash` for types that doesn't depend on a type you defined yourself.

That said, this hack might work:

```
template<class T, class E>
using first = T;

template <typename T>
struct hash<first<std::pair<T, T>, std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>>>
{
    size_t operator()(const std::pair<T, T>& x) const
    {
        return x;
    }
};
```

Really, though, don't do this. Write your own hasher.

Comment: There is a good reason not to specialize `std::hash` for pairs/tuples: I would really expect a auto-combining hash will show up in `std` at some point shortly.

Comment: Why is `first` needed in here? That is, why not `std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<T>::value, T>`? Isn't `enable_if` supposed to do what `first` does in here?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work on clang https://godbolt.org/z/qjTMEvbse