# Pattern-match/SFINAE on parameterization of container for specific classes?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I have `Base` class and some `Derived` classes.  Certain bit patterns that come in from external code can make these, and there is generic code which builds them.  That generic code has to use an explicit template "factory":

```
auto d = factory<D>(data); // where D is some Derived class
```

This factory is SFINAE-enabled for classes that are derived from Base:

```
template<
    class T,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value
    >::type
>
T factory(ExternalData &data) {
    T result;
    if (!result.initFromData(&data))
        throw std::runtime_error("data is not set");
    return result;
}
```

I'd like to add another variant that works with [`std::experimental::optional<Derived>`](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional) for the cases when the bit patterns indicate things are unset.  In this case the generic code would be passing in either type:

```
auto dod = factory<DOD>(data); // DOD can be Derived or std::optional<Derived>
```

Using explicit parameterization like this, how would I create another SFINAE variant which would "pattern match" into existence only for for `std::experimental::optional<any class whose base is Base>`?

The desire would be if I could write:

```
template<
    std::experimental::optional<class T>, // imaginary
    typename = typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value
    >::type
>
std::optional<T> factory(ExternalData &data) {
    T result;
    if (!result.initFromData(&data))
        return nullopt;
    return result;
}
```

Is there a non-imaginary version of implementing the desire?  I looked at ["using SFINAE for template class specialisation"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12858839/211160) (and several others) and it seems like maybe there are some ways to cooperatively hack something together to do it with a container if I wrote it (?), but am I missing an easy answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct extract_optional;

template <typename T>
struct extract_optional<std::experimental::optional<T>>
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
using extract_optional_t = typename extract_optional<T>::type;

template <
    typename T,
    typename OP = extract_optional_t<T>,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_base_of<Base, OP>::value
    >::type
>
std::experimental::optional<OP> factory(ExternalData &data) {
    OP result;
    if (!result.initFromData(&data))
        return nullopt;
    return result;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0568b423475741d4)

Comment: Problems solved in real-time!  :-)  Thanks very much.  It seems to do the trick and makes good sense...I'll need to test it a little more to be sure it works.  One thing I do recall about these kinds of things is that in order to keep them from getting fouled up if someone happens to provide an explicit parameterization for OP is a static assert.  Something like that T is equal to std::experimental::optional<T>...

Comment: @HostileFork or just [inline all occurences of `extract_optional_t`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7bd80c9ee7b9ae9)

Comment: Even better.  Will do.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? I'm very interested in the point of your answer unfortunately it's too succinct for me to understand

Comment: @Rerito `extract_optional` is established as a prototype of a templated structure.  If there were no definitions of it anywhere, you couldn't use it with anything, and [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) would gracefully fail in all cases that tried to use it.  But it is specialized as being allowed to be used with one thing: `optional<OP>`...so it only succeeds in instantiating there.  We get the two things we wanted: the OP contained type for checking and use, plus assurance that T was a std::optional<OP> (with the caveat I noted, fixed via inlining.)